# What trust level do i need to build a ecommerce web site with mysql database?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm helping building a ecommerce web site for a friend, he would like to use asp.net with mysql back end to store products and be able to update,delete, and insert data.

My question is are you able to build a asp.net 4.0 medium trust web site with mysql database?
If so how would you do it?

any help would be great thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the mysql database is no problem - just add it as a connection in visual studio and you can start accessing it just like any other database. However if you want to use a lot of the built in membership controls (Login/membership creation/url security via roles etc) then:

You need to download the mysql adodb.net connector. This will then allow you to use the membership/role providers (it also will create the database schema for you when first accessed if there is not one present)

[MySql ADODB connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

If you want to test whether your application will run in medium trust you can add a web.config variable during development

[MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx)

i.e.

```
<system.web>
  <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue with running mysql in medium trust. Full trust is only required when you are calling methods decorated with CAS attributes. These can range from special file/folder methods, attempting to read/modify the loaded HttpModules in the asp.net pipeline (ones that I have come across)

Comment: i have a middle tier where i call all my methods however on one page I'm asynchronous displaying images from a database would that need a full trust?

Comment: Almost certainly not - but to test just add the web.config trust element and run it on your development machine. If what you have coded does require full trust it will error at that point. If you don't want to code it but know what methods you will call in the .net libraries you can examine the class in .net lib using ILsharp (decompiler)